# Seam in band 1 of sentinel 2 data

Tags: sentinel-2

I am processing sentinel 2 data and while most bands look fine I have noticed an odd seam in band 1 of several images as can be seen from the attached image.

[image]

The image is cut from the ESA scene S2A_MSIL2A_20190921T101031_N0213_R022_T33VWD_20190921T130515 and displayed using only the value range 0-300 of band 1.

What type of artefact is this seam? Is it an error with my processing or a property of the instrument or what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seam is not visible only on your L2A image, but also on L1C images, such as this one (created [with EO Browser](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?lat=57.6270&lng=15.8354&zoom=11&time=2019-09-21&preset=CUSTOM&datasource=Sentinel-2%20L1C&evalscript=cmV0dXJuIFtCMDFdLm1hcChhPT4yLjUqYSk7)):
[image: Sentinel-2A L1C Image taken on 2019-09-21]

This suggests that the banding is caused by aerosol scattering, which affects odd detectors differently than even ones because they look at the ground at slightly different angles (Sentinel-2 has 12 detectors in a staggered configuration, see e.g. Figure 4 of [the MSI Overview](https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/msi-instrument) ).

Ideally this effect of the aerosol would be removed by the atmospheric correction processor, but in this case a lot of it remains in the L2A surface reflectance image. I checked the latest [L2A Data Quality Report](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/document-library/-/asset_publisher/Wk0TKajiISaR/content/sentinel-2-l2a-data-quality-report-issue-01-may-2018-) and this issue does not seem to be mentioned specifically.